# How prevent use AirPlay on iPhone on my Next/React project

Tags: reactjs, iphone, next.js, react-player

On my project(Next.js/React.js) **react-player** worked fine for a long time.
Then I decided to encrypt the link, and it worked fine, but after about a week, audio via **AirPlay** started to play on the iPhone, which is very inconvenient.

I didn’t quite understand how it happened, because I didn’t change anything, and the person said that a week ago everything was OK, and when he came in, it started to connect AirPlay.

```
<ReactPlayer
            id='soundPlayer'
            height='1px'
            width='1px'
            ref={this.ref}
            playing={playing}
            volume={1}
            url={file}
            onPlay={this.onPlay}
            onPause={this.onPause}
            onProgress={this.onProgress}
            onDuration={this.onDuration}
            file='forceAudio'/>
```

The player's settings are the most common and haven't changed for a long time.
Everything is fine in all other browsers and devices (MacBook, Sumsung, etc).

Is there a way to tell the iPhone not to use AirPlay?
Very thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

ohh, sorry, is is so easy => add playsinline={true} attr